# How do I define the compilation file in 0.9.5

Tags: typescript

I recently upgraded to 0.9.5 and instead of using build events to compile my typescript application, I decided to use the built in options in the project settings page. Specifically the tickbox that 'compile(s) javascript into one file'

In short I cannot get the files to compile in the correct order. The compilation is fine but when I run it, I can see that the files order is not correct so sub classes throw errors because their base classes are not defined.

Previously (in the build events method) I would specify the file I am compiling ('Main.ts'). Inside the target Main.ts file I used a number of reference tags to other files and that would compile everything into a single file all in the correct order.

Now in 0.9.5 I dont know how Im supposed to that. There is no option to specify which file is the one I want to compile. On their blog entry they mention using a _references.ts file. I cant find any documentation on this - so I presume this is correct:

I create a file  called _references.ts which supposedly is passed to the compiler first. Inside that file I list all my reference commands like so:

```
/// <reference path="core/a.ts" />
/// <reference path="core/b.ts" />
/// <reference path="core/c.ts" />
```

But if I do this the compilation keeps randomising the build order. Its like its completely ignoring either the _references.ts file or the reference tags of that file. (I've tried putting them into another file but how do I tell it that that file must be passed first?)

Im probably wrong, but its my suspicion that its compiling all the files and it just so happens that the _references file comes in last.

So in short... How do I tell the compiler (in the new 0.9.5 settings panel) to compile everything into 1 file and also keep the order.

Thanks online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_references.ts` can be used to control the order of your combined output.

**Make sure you are using `_references.ts` somewhere in at least one of your `.ts` files, otherwise the compiler doesn't know about the existence.**

To do so, add a reference to the `_references.ts` in one or more of your .ts files ;)

Now order the `.ts` references within that file as you want.

I tested it with the Raytracer example from the playground. 
I split all components into separated files and added the references... , my `_references.ts` looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="IThing.ts" />
/// <reference path="ISurface.ts" />
/// <reference path="IScene.ts" />
/// <reference path="IRay.ts" />
/// <reference path="IIntersection.ts" />
/// <reference path="ILight.ts" />
/// <reference path="Vector.ts" />
/// <reference path="Color.ts" />
/// <reference path="Camera.ts" />
/// <reference path="Sphere.ts" />
/// <reference path="Plane.ts" />
/// <reference path="Surfacse.ts" />
/// <reference path="RayTracer.ts" />
/// <reference path="Init.ts" />
```

I also used the option to generate one output file and it generates it in perfect order...

Comment: Hi MichaC, I think I figured out what was wrong. I created the references file, however it was not in the root directory of the project. Not sure if this is an issue or not - but it only seems to work for me if I do that. Originally I had it in a sub folder.

Comment: no it must not be in the root. It is just important to notice that the `path` of each reference is a relative path to the location of the _reference.ts. Meaning if you have it in a sub directory, the path to the referenced files must reflect that, otherwise the compiler cannot find the files...

And as I mentioned, you must reference the _reference.ts at least once in your other .ts files ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a pretty bad bug in the way VS compiles the `_references.ts` file during a full build (meaning `Ctrl+F5` opposed to just `Ctrl+S`).

If you're having problems getting `_references.ts` to put your files in the corrcet order please see my question and answer here:

[Visual Studio 2013 Typescript compiler isn't respecting '_references.ts' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902107/visual)

The simple fix is to edit the `.csproj` file (unload project first) and then move the `_references.ts` file to be first in the list of included ts files.