# Visual Studio 2013 Typescript compiler isn't respecting '_references.ts' file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and have been working the last few days within Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 (which natively includes all support).

I have the following options selected within Visual Studio on the properties page for my project.

This means that when I save a file it will automatically compile all the typescript files together and create a single `RRStore.js` file. I then just include this using the BundleManager in ASP.NET as if it were any old JS file. I am not using a module loaders since there's not much JS code.

[image]

To resolve dependencies in the correct order the TS compiler needs a `_references.ts` file so I created one like this :

```
/// <reference path="RR.ErrorHandling.ts" />
/// <reference path="RR.JQueryPlugins.ts" />
/// <reference path="RR.Util.ts" />

/// <reference path="viewmodel/UserViewModel.ts" />

/// <reference path="viewmodel/AddressViewModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="viewmodel/ProductViewModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="viewmodel/CartItemViewModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="viewmodel/CheckoutViewModel.ts" />

/// <reference path="viewmodel/StoreWizardViewModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="viewmodel/DefenderWizardViewModel.ts" />

/// <reference path="viewmodel/MainViewModel.ts" />

/// <reference path="RR.YoutubeLoader.ts" />
```

This file means when I hit `Ctrl+S` within Visual Studio after editing a TS file it will combine all my other TS files together in this order so things such as prototype chains are correct for inheritance.

This was working fine on `Ctrl+S` when saving a TS file.

I then had to make a change to some C# code - after which of course I needed to hit `Ctrl+F5` to build the project. To my surprise I got weird JS errors in the browser - about prototypes not existing on objects.

I looked at the generated Typescript file `RRStore.js` in the browser and examined the order of all my files and it's put the file `RR.YoutubeLoader.ts` FIRST.

That's weird! (not least because it's LAST on my list of references above.)

I went to that file and hit `Ctrl+S`, refreshed `RRStore.js` and everything is back in the right order.

In other words when I do a full build the order of files in `_references.ts` is not respected, but when I just hit `Ctrl+S` it is. What's going on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Edit:* Update: Turns out `_references.ts` needs to be in the root of your project to be recognized by the compiler. So that's the preferred way :-) This method works too... but please don't do this:

---

*Original workaround:*

When reading through my generated `RRStore.js` file I noticed the order seemed to be in an apparently random order: `RR.YoutubeLoader`, `ProductViewModel`, `DefenderViewModel`, `StoreViewModel` etc.

I realized there could be only one explanation....

I opened up the `.csproj` file and sure enough **the compiler was processing files in the order they had been initially added to my project**!!!.

So I moved the `_references.ts` file up to the first in the `MySite.csproj` file - and it is now correctly recognizing it and compiling everything in the right order.

I'm not sure if this is a known bug yet but that was an adequate solution for me.

#### MyProject.csproj

[image]

Comment: I've reported this through Visual studio directly. If anyone is aware of an existing bug report (or reason why this isn't a bug which I'd be surprised by) please post a link to it here

Comment: We have just run into this same issue, and, your comments the same day.  Initial tests show that this fixes the issue...I would say it is a bug and I am not aware of a bug report.

Comment: Update: _references.ts apparently needs to be in the root of your project to be recognized by the compiler as designed

Comment: Wow, I've been suffering with it for hours now.. thank you. Wonder why there is nothing on the internet about it.

Comment: This is still the case in vs2015.1, _references.ts needs to be in the root of the project.

Comment: man, you save my life :) I was looking for a solution over 3 hours.... _references.ts at the first place solved all problems with missing references, enums and other starnge errors reported in visual studio . Big coffie for you :)

Answer (score 6):

Sooooo....

Apparently `_references.ts` needs to be in the root of the project.

I haven't tested this but this is a response from https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2592

I still prefer my way of manually editing the csproj file (so my ts files are all `inside Scripts/Typescript`). Hopefully sometime they'll change this unintuitive behavior and look for _references.ts wherever it is.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any reference to this in the typescript bug tracker, so I have created one at https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2592

Comment: thanks. it's also the same in the absolute latest VS2013 - I didn't start using TS until the recent milestone release